# ObservableCollection passed as parameter and Interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, observablecollection

I have an interface `IPerson` and two classes, `Adventurer` and `Worker` that implement it. I currently have separate `ObservableCollection`s for Adventurers and Workers. I have a method that I would like to be able to pass both an `ObservableCollection<Adventurer>` and an `ObservableCollection<Worker>` to as a parameter and so far I haven't had any luck. The method uses only properties implemented in `IPerson` and if I declare it as:

```
public void MyMethod(ObservableCollection<IPerson> collection)
```

...there are no errors inside the method itself. However, when I try to pass in an `ObservableCollection<Adventurer>`, I get 2 errors:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'`

and

> The best overloaded method match for 'AoW.MyMethod(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection)' has some invalid arguments`

Is it possible for me to pass both `ObservableCollection`s to the same method? If so, how should I go about it? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes in .NET don't support [covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx). Only interfaces do. Imagine  this scenario:

```
class Adventurer : IPerson { }
class NPC : IPerson { }

public void MyMethod(ObservableCollection<IPerson> collection)
{
    collection.Add(new NPC());
}

var collectionOfAdventurers = new ObservableCollection<Adventurer>();
MyMethod(collectionOfAdventurers);
```

This would obviously raise some errors because the type passed in was an `Adventurer` collection, but the method added an `NPC`, but this cannot be verified at compile time. So rather than allow such unsafe behavior, the compiler requires that the type passed in must exactly match the type in the signature, and gives an error if you try to pass in anything else.

I'd recommend changing `MyMethod` to:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<IPerson> enumerable)
```

Or

```
public void MyMethod(INotifyCollectionChanged collection)
```

depending on exactly what members you need to access.

You might also want to consider a generic method:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection) where T : IPerson
```

Comment: Changing to an `IEnumerable<IPerson>` did the trick. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way because

```
ObservableCollection<IPerson>
```

Is
 itself another type (for example, you could put both an Adventurer or a Worker in it, you can't do it in a collection of adventurer or worker)

A solution could be to allow a IEnumerable of IPerson in your method and then to call it using :

```
ObservableCollection<Worker> col = ...
MyMethod(col.Cast<IPerson>());
```